# npm ERR! code 1 command failed C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

After running `npm i`, I am getting a 'code 1' error and a 'deadsync' error. I couldn't figure out the reason.

I recently switched to a new computer, and that might be the reason for encountering this error.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ufukc\Desktop\Aydin\work\aydin_tasarim\tekstil\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.34114.132) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ufukc\\Desktop\\Aydin\\work\\aydin_tasarim\\tekstil\\node_modules\\deasync\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.9.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.9.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\ufukc\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.9.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',    
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\ufukc\\Desktop\\Aydin\\work\\aydin_tasarim\\tekstil\\node_modules\\deasync',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ufukc\\Desktop\\Aydin\\work\\aydin_tasarim\\tekstil\\node_modules\\deasync\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\ufukc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\ufukc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\ufukc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\ufukc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.23570
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ufukc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ufukc\Desktop\Aydin\work\aydin_tasarim\tekstil\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486526/windows-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils)

Comment: I fixed

First delete package-lock.json after 

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with this steps:

1. Delete the package-lock.json
2. Run this `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`