# self created module not callable

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am trying to create a python package so after creating the folder with all my files in it including a `__init__.py` file I moved the folder into /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/.

When I try to use `import ClockTower`(name of the folder) It returns with

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'ClockTower'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're not able to `import ClockTower` successfully is that you haven't actually installed it.

### [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html)

If the package is just for personal use on your own machine I would recommend using `distutils` to create a simple `setup.py` script to enable installation of your package - `distutils` is often distributed as a built-in package, however Debian based systems may not have it by default ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626034/importerror-no-module-named-distutils)).

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#) is some step-by-step documentation on creating a `setup.py` script that will enable you to install and use your package across the system.

If you just want a quick and minimal solution, first create a new directory, then create a file called `setup.py` within this folder put the directory containing package files/code inside also.

Your enclosing folder should look something like this - additional files/directories in `ClockTower` are omitted here for clarity.

```
/home/usr/Desktop/EnclosingDir
├───setup.py
│
└───ClockTower
    └───__init__.py
```

`setup.py` should look something like this to define a basic install of the `ClockTower` package.

```py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='ClockTower',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['ClockTower'],
)
```

To install your package for use by the specified interpreter (here `python3.8`) , simply navigate to the enclosing folder that contains `setup.py` and run.

```sh
python3.8 -m pip install .
```

You should see some console output and if the install has been successful you should see `ClockTower 1.0.0` listed when you run `python3.8 -m pip list` and be able to successfully `import ClockTower` using this interpreter.

**Important note:** This approach does not account for any external dependencies (e.g. non-built-in packages/modules) of `ClockTower`, it assumes that these will be available by the interpreter - e.g. already installed using something like a `requirements.txt` install procedure.

### [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`setuptools` is a much more fully featured library for distributing Python packages. This feature-richness comes at the cost of increased complexity/time to learn and implement.

If you are going to be sharing this package with others I would recommend checking out the [`setuptools` user guide](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html) and following along to create a robust and portable distribution of your package.